# android how to deal with android timer when phone goes to sleep

Tags: android, timer, task

Our Application has a service which starts a timer to schedule a task every 4 hours.
But the phone often goes to sleep when the screen is off.
I don't expect the task to run when the phone is sleeping.
But I want that it can be run immediately if the phone has slept longer than 4 hours.

```
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() 
{

            @Override
    public void run() {
                          //do something
        }
    };

new Timer().schedule(task, 0,  4*60*60*1000);//period=4 hours;
```

I have done some tests that show if then phone has slept for more than 4 hours and when it wakes up, the timer's period didn't add the past 5 sleep hours and it can't run the task immediately.
Its period time just calculates the phone's wake time.
I have studied Timer.java, and know the timer's delay mechanism is to use thread wait(), that is the reason.
How to make a cyclic time task that contains the phone sleep time?
I think there is no need to use an AlarmManager, because the task doesn't need to run when the phone is sleeping.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use powermanager wake lock http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Timer, you need to use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) without the wakeup option set. If you do this the alarm will trigger the next time you wake up the phone after the 4 hours..

Check out this tutorial: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/use-androids-alarmmanager-to-schedule-an-event/